# Continuity and limits by replacing y by lambda*x

Tags: limits, continuity

if the limit does not exist for a function, does that mean it is not continuous?

$f(x) = \dfrac {xy }{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ when $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ else it is 0.

For example, if you replace $y$ by $\lambda x$, you will see that the limit does not exist, does that prove that it is not continuous? I know that if you replace $y$ by $x$, you will see that $f(x,x) = 0.5$ which is not $(0,0)$. But is that ok to just prove that the limit does not exist by the previous way i just said?

Comment: yes, it is ok to prove that it can have multiple limits. continuity requires a single and finite limit, as soon as you find at least $2$ then it is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

$f $ is continuous at $(0,0)$

$$\iff \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f (x,y)=f (0,0)=0$$

$$\implies \lim_{\lambda \to 0}f (x,\lambda x)=0$$

if the last limit doesn't exist,  the function $f $ is not continuous at $(0,0) $.